# Winforms control Custom Border and BorderWidth affecting ClientRectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, border

I'm struggling with a seemingly unique problem...I have a custom control with two properties (amongst others) called **Border** and **BorderWidth**. What I noticed was that setting these values affects the value of the ClientRectangle of the control.

As far as I'm aware, WinForms controls don't have "Border" and "BorderWidth" properties so I can't be inadvertently setting any base properties that might be causing this. Here is the issue...I have the following properties:

```
/// <summary>
/// Whether or not this control has a border
/// </summary>
[Browsable(true)]
public bool Border {
  get {
    return _border;
  }
  set {
    _border = value;
    this.Invalidate();
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// The width (in pixels) of the controls border
/// </summary>
[Browsable(true)]
public int BorderWidth {
  get {
    return _borderWidth;
  }
  set {
    if (value <= 1) value = 1;
      _borderWidth = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I have put breakpoints in both of the setters above and as soon as either the the `_border = value` or `_borderWidth = value` lines are executed the value of `this.ClientRectangle` immediately changes. It's as if the values of these properties are being read by the .Net Framework and used to adjust `this.ClientRectaangle`. I don't have any code that does this, and I couldn't either since `ClientRectangle` is read-only anyway.

**Before running the line `_border = value` (Setting the value to "true")**

```
Border = false
BorderWidth = 1
this.ClientRectangle = {X=0 Y=0 Width=150 Height=29}
```

**After**

```
Border = true
BorderWidth = 1
this.ClientRectangle = {X=1 Y=1 Width=148 Height=27}
```

**Before running the `_borderWidth = value` (setting the value to "2")**

```
Border = true
BorderWidth = 1
this.ClientRectangle = {X=1 Y=1 Width=148 Height=27}
```

**After**

```
Border = true
BorderWidth = 2
this.ClientRectangle = {X=2 Y=2 Width=146 Height=25}
```

I don't understand how this is possible and since I'm using `this.ClientRectangle` in the Paint event to draw a border and other things, I end up drawing on a space smaller than the actual size of the control; the border in particular isn't drawn to the edges of the control by the following code:

```
private void DrawBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle r) {
    if (Border) {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, ClientRectangle, BorderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            BorderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            BorderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
            BorderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        //float halfBorder = (float)BorderWidth / 2;
        //RectangleF r2 = new RectangleF(halfBorder, halfBorder, (float)r.Size.Width - halfBorder, (float)r.Size.Height - halfBorder);
        //g.DrawRectangles(new Pen(BorderColor, BorderWidth), new RectangleF[] { r2 });
    }
}
```

Apologies for the long post, just thought to provide as much information as possible to improve the chance of getting a solution.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way a **true** border behaves.  My crystal ball says that you got started on your control with code that you downloaded somewhere and it implemented a real border.

Look for an override of WndProc().  Windows sends the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message to ask a window to specify its borders.  And sends `WM_NCPAINT` to ask the window to paint them.  You'll want to either take advantage of these messages, and move your painting code to whatever existing code there is now when WM_NCPAINT is received.  Or delete that code completely so your can use *OnPaintBackground* to draw your custom border.  You typically also need to turn on the ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw style flag to prevent "smearing" when the control gets resized when it, say, is anchored on all 4 sides.

Comment: Thanks Hans, your crystal ball is partially correct. I have a WndProc() override which started life elsewhere. However it doesn't have code that responds to the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message. What I do have, egg-on-face time, is my own override of ClientRectangle which I wrote myself (no cut and paste here) but had completely forgotten about! Doh! My ClientRectangle property recalculates X, Y, Width and Height depending on _border and _borderWidth to provide said **true** border behaviour.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as it came closest to helping me track down my own faux pas.

Comment: Maybe there's a small nugget in the "real border" details I gave, but it is probably more appropriate if you delete the question.

Comment: Wouldn't dream of deleting the question...I've found lots of useful information on SO in seemingly unrelated posts and I think your mention of `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and `WM_NCPAINT` would be helpful to someone else someday.

Answer (score 0):

When a rectangle is drawn with some line width, we have 3 sizes, the outer size is equal to the `ClientRectangle` size and the inner size is `2*lineWidth` less wider than `ClientRectangle` width and `2*lineWidth` less higher than the `ClientRectangle` height. The last size is the middle/center size which has the width being `lineWidth` less wider than the `ClientRectangle` width and the height being `lineWidth` less higher than the `ClientRectangle` height. You can calculate the exact `Rectangle` used with the `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` as following:

```
var rect = ClientRectangle;
rect.Width -= borderWidth;
rect.Height -= borderWidth;
rect.Offset(borderWidth/2, borderWidth/2);
//then use the rect instead of the ClientRectangle 
//in your ControlPaint.DrawBorder
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, rect, ....
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely useful for drawing the border properly but I still need to understand why/how `ClientRectangle` is being "automatically" updated when setting my custom properties; "what you don't understand will turn round and bite you" :-).